# Referencing equation without the need of labels

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, links

Is it possible to have automatic labelling (non-descriptive) for equations in LaTeX?

I would like to know if the equation number can be referenced in the document without the need for having to create a `\label{}` and `\ref{}` every time.

I hope you understand what I am getting at...

If not, is it possible to use a package which creates labels (again non-descriptive) for every equation automatically?

Comment: `\label` and `\ref` is how the referencing works. That is how it is and there is no automatic way to generate labels as what your be a big mess. One could base such a label generating macro on the contents of the equation, but that of course changes if you change the equation which defies the idea that labels should be fixed in time.

Comment: @daleif Ok, thanks for clarifying that for me, I just started using LaTeX, so I wasn't very sure, and finding anything on StackExchange is honestly impossible with the dumb reputation requirement to comment on old posts, so thanks.

Comment: The reputation stuff is actually quite good to keep spammers at bay. Your question comes up from time to time, and the answer is always the same. For searching the site Google is your friend